# Why is a function name required here?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've been testing this in the browser console of FireFox, not sure if other javascript environments have this:

```
◄ {x:function(){console.log("test");}}["x"]();
► SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
```

Why? This works though:

```
◄ ({x:function(){console.log("test");}})["x"]();
► undefined
► "test"
```

(In case anyone is wondering: I really hate the switch,case,break syntax. I'd rather use this construction.)

Comment: FYI: Chrome gives an "Unexpected token (" error

Comment: Chrome is apparently weird in more ways then one there:
`{x:1}`
1 _(one?!)_
`{x:1,y:2}`
SyntaxError: Unexpected token : _(huh?)_

Comment: ah, but `({x:1,y:2})` Object {x: 1, y: 2}
I guess it's a statement<>expression thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are creating a block. As [MDN describes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block):

> A block statement is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets.

This is a block:

```
{}
```

It is a statement. It does not return anything. All it does is group zero or more other statements together. When Javascript sees `{` at the beginning of a line, it thinks "aha, we have a block here".

This, however, is not a block:

```
({})
```

That is an expression. It has a return value. Here, in an expression context, `{}` delimits an object literal, not a block.

So, with your code, let's break it up a bit:

```
{ // start a block
    x: // create a label called x
    function(){console.log("test");} // create a function expression
} // end the block
["x"](); // create an array with one element and attempt to execute it as a function
```

Now, the last line would obviously fail, but we never get there. When Javascript sees `function` at the beginning of a line, it expects a function statement. You are giving it an anonymous function expression. This is invalid in this context and causes an error.

---

By contrast, your other statement:

```
( // start an expression
    { // create an object
        x: function(){console.log("test");} // create a property called x with an anonymous function as its value
    } // end the object
) // end the expression and return the object
["x"] // get the `x` property from the returned object
(); // execute it
```

Answer (score 5):

The brackets in the first one is resulting in a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

The first one looks like this when the semicolons are injected

```
{
    x : function() { 
        console.log("test");
    }
};
["x"]();
```

Answer (score 3):

Syntax of JavaScript can be ambiguous. First example is parsed as opening of block (`{`) followed by label (`x:`, the one you would jump to by `break` or `continue`), then *function declaration*. When declaring functions, you have to provide name.

Second example is parsed as an expression, as it is enclosed in parentheses (`(`), so `{` is interpreted as anonymous object with `x` property, which value is *function expression*. Function statements can be anonymous.

Comment: There is no goto in js.  Labels are used with `break` and `continue`.

Comment: How can it be JavaScript does not have `goto`? Now I know why some real programmers dismiss JavaScript as toy programming language...

Answer (score 0):

In Opera 12.16, it does basically the same thing, except telling you

```
["x"] is not a function
```

Which it really isn't:
In your first statement, you define

```
{x:function(){console.log("test");}}
```

If you enter this on your own, it will evaluate to

```
function(){console.log("test");}
```

But if you put no parentheses around it, it will do just that, evaluate to an anonymous object and begone for the rest of your statement.
If you put a dot like this:

```
{x:function(){console.log("test");}}.x
```

There will be a syntax error. if you do

```
({x:function(){console.log("test");}}).x
```

it will work.